# read lines in file into 2 variables in shellscript

Tags: shell

I have a file with 2 lines and I want to read them into 2 variables respectively.  How do I accomplish this in shellscript(bash)?

Answer (score 2):

You can open file descriptors in a shell to read the variables:

```
#!/bin/bash

# open file
exec 6<tst.txt

read foo <&6
read bar <&6

# close file again
exec 6<&-

echo $foo $bar
```

EDIT:

As a quick explanation, this is using IO redirection.  Normally the file descriptors are handled as follows:

- 0 stdin   (input)
- 1 stdout  (output)
- 2 stderr  (error)

However, there's nothing preventing from using other file descriptors (up to 9), so we're opening the "tst.txt" file in file descriptor 6, and read from it using [IO redirection](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html).

So, `exec 6<tst.txt` opens file descriptor 6 and redirects `tst.txt` into it, whereas `exec 6<&-` closes it again.

Comment: It works! But could you further explain, especially what the 2 exec command do? Is there any special meaning of using "6"?

Answer (score 1):

I'm unfortunately not on linux right now to test, but this would be close.

```
#!/bin/bash
file="/path/to/file"
# Store the previous IFS so we don't break anything else in the script.
prevIFS='$IFS'
# You need the line break to capture a newline.
IFS='
'
read var1 var2 < $file
echo "Var1: $var1"
echo "Var2: $var2"

# Set IFS back to normal
IFS='$prevIFS'
```

Comment: You'll need to use `<`, (send this *file* to `read`) not `<<<` (send this *string* to `read`). Also, you need quotes around `$IFS` and `$prevIFS` or they *will* be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest answer would be using `sed` command. Assuming that your file name is file.txt

```
var1=($(sed '1q;d' file.txt))
var2=($(sed '2q;d' file.txt))
```

Where `1q` and `2q` defines the  line number.
All the values in Line 1 will be assigned to var1 and similarly to var2.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
#!/bin/bash

I=0
while read; do
  VAR[$I]=$REPLY
  ((I++))
done < file

echo ${VAR[0]}
echo ${VAR[1]}
```

this will work with a file with more than 2 lines

Answer (score 0):

Can you reconfigure the input file (with variables) to work as shell code? i.e.

```
 $ cat varFile
     var1=xyz
     var2=abc

 $ cat myShellScript.sh
   #/bin/whatever (bash)?

   # source the variable file
   . /path/to/varFile

   echo $var1
   echo $var2
```

This is a standard concept in shell scripting and makes it much easier to manage configuration issues where you need to control your (unix/linux) environment based on which physical hardware you are running your system. If this is part of you concern, please let me know and I'll update the sample code to extend on this technique.

I hope this helps.